# Manual Deserialization method with Java Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I need to create a method that will deserialize an XML file into an object using only Java Reflection.

The method itself is the following:

`public T deserialize(String data) {}`

Where data is the file name (animal.xml for example). Could someone point me to how this can be achieved using reflection to obtain the field values and set them to the new instance I will be returning?

I am aware of the Reflection API in Java, have used it on a basic level to get and set values of a class that I already have created.

Any advice is welcome as this has taken me too long to figure out and I don't really know what are the right questions to ask. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure about the reflection-only constraint? Reflection in Java just allows for dynamic invocation and lookup on arbitrary, existing object state and methods or their dynamic instantiation. It is not responsible for tokenizing, lexing or parsing XML documents at all.

Comment: Hi, yes unfortunately the constraints are that I have to use reflection with generics in order to parse the file and I cannot use external libraries.

Comment: IMO this requirement doesn't make much sense. Is this part of some education/training or interview thing? Or has one of your superior given you this task? While it is possible to create new objects via reflection and assign properties to that object, without any concrete class structure the usage of these objects are rather questionable. How do you "parse" the XML document? Some pseudo-algorithm would evolve around recognizing XML elements, create a new object for each element assign any attributes belonging to an element to the created object representing that element and so on

Comment: Further, is `T` in your pseudo-code an actual object or a type? In case of a type, Java will erase these and replace them with a generic Object (or the respective bound defined) at runtime. Unless you carry around the actual class `T` refers to, you will have to deal with objects here anyway and not being able to cast that object to a `T`

Comment: Yes, the T is for Type and also yes its a task I must complete. To be honest I also can't make sense of this with Reflection to have an xml document turned into an Object. I asked here since more opinions on this is better than just me wondering how this can be achieved. I have refactored the method to have a return type of Object rather than a T. Still, even if I manage to get the values for the fields, how would I go to set them via reflection on a new instance? The document is just a text after all. Thanks again!

Comment: I'd define my own class that contains a map for the attributes an element has and their values and also some properties that allow me to depict the parent-child nature of an XML document. You can then instantiate a new object via reflection if you really have to and assign the attributes to that map, which also can be done via reflection quite easily. The XML tree structure should also be straight forward this way. The only thing you have to figure out here is to convert that to a `T`, whatever that will be. Good luck on your journey though

Comment: Thanks, I'll figure it out eventually!